# Parsing JSON response in Swift 3

Tags: json, swift, http

I've got an API endpoint that returns JSON in the following format:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "John"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Jane"
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "Nick"
  }
]
```

I am trying to parse this in Swift 3, but I can only find examples to parse JSON formatted like so:

```
{
"blogs": [
    {
        "needspassword": true,
        "id": 73,
        "url": "http://remote.bloxus.com/",
        "name": "Bloxus test"
    },
    {
        "needspassword": false,
        "id": 74,
        "url": "http://flickrtest1.userland.com/",
        "name": "Manila Test"
    }
],
"stat": "ok"
}
```

, which has an extra level above what mine does.

So, where examples I've seen are simply parsing their data like `jsonResponse["blogs"]`, I can't do that as my format is different.

How can I parse the format I've got, or how can I return a format that is easier to parse?

Any suggestions appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will parse it when placed in the network call.

```
        do {
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions()) as! [[String : AnyObject]]
            let firstPerson = json[0]
            print(firstPerson)
            let id = firstPerson["id"] as! String
            print(id)
            let name = firstPerson["name"] as! String
            print(name)
        } catch {
            //handle error
        }
```

Also, I tend to be against advising third party libraries, but SwiftyJSON is an exception I make. If you want to try it, add this to your pod file:

pod SwiftyJSON', '3.0.0'

Documentation: https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

**EDIT - Answering Comment:**

Replacement line:

```
if let id = firstPerson["id"] as? String {
    print(id)
}
```

Replacement line (if you need to hold on to the value):

```
var thisId: String?
if let id = firstPerson["id"] as? String {
    thisId = id
}
print(thisId ?? "")
```

Comment: Well i am late but i was wondering something. In this line: `let id = firstPerson["id"] as! String`. If the `firstPerson["id"]` value is nil, won't it cause a crash?

Comment: yes, the replacement line would be something I'll add in an edit

Answer (score 2):

You can just do the following :

```
    let data = // Data received from WS
    do {
        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions()) as? [[String : String]]
        //json is now an array from dictionary matching your model
    }
    catch {
       //handle error
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

i don't really know swift but there might be the equivalent of ajax json encoding (server side you json_encode your array and client side you json_decode the response)

the idea is to have the same formatter that encodes and decodes the data

Comment: Don't ever answer a language specific question starting your answer with 
"i don't really know _____". Spend your time on stack overflow checking out the questions that apply to your knowledge bank.